# jquery vertical slider handle not moving

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins, slider

> I am using jquery slider as vertical orientation bt vertical slider handle not moving.Please help, i know i am missing something obvious.
>   [--Demo here--](http://jsfiddle.net/D45mp/31/)

```
$( ".slider" ).slider({
       animate: true,
orientation:"vertical",
           range: "min",
           value: 50,
           min: 0,
           max: 100,
           step: 1,
           slide: function( event, ui ) {
               $("#slider-result").html( ui.value );
           }
           });
```

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/D45mp/32/)

I've simply removed `top: -3px;` 
from `.ui-slider-handle`

If you want to set the start position of a slider to the top, use value parameter in your slider function (value = 100).

Answer (score 0):

Just Remove `top:-3px;` in `.ui-slider-handle`.